# Unable to set up button with tag

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, button, tags

I have a cell that I want to use and I just want a outlet for the button in the cell so I can display a dropdown menu. I'm trying to make a button with a tag using this code

```
var dropdownButton: UIButton = (PostCell.viewWithTag(200) as! UIButton)
```

I'm using it in the cellForRowAtIndexPath but the thing is I keep getting a error saying

"Use of instance member 'viewWithTag' on type 'UIView'; did you mean to use a value of type 'UIView' Instead?

Comment: viewWIthTag is a method you can use on UIVIew type objects. POSTCell is not a UIView.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the code as

```
var dropdownButton: UIButton = (postCell.contentView.viewWithTag(200) as? UIButton)
```

You are using `PostCell` seems like you are directly accessing it through class name. Try to access with the object of the `UITableViewCell`. All the views on `UITableViewCell` are placed on its contentView so access the button from there.

Also use `?` to get the object as button because if you use `!` app may get crash if the object not found for tag 200 due to some reason.

To prevent app from crashing use `?`.